# How to resolve hostname from local IP in C#.NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to list the names of the computer names currently online on a network. I've only managed to get the get active IPs but I cannot get the computer name of these IPs. Any ideas ?

Comment: Depending on what network you are talking about the answers below will not work for you. Please specify what environment you are talking about and if the computers involved have public IPs.

Comment: In addition, OP asked for "COMPUTERNAME", not hostname, right?

Comment: I'm working on Windows 7 and using local IPs only (192.168.....)

Comment: As Astyanax pointed out you are most likely talking about computer names and not host names.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [Dns.GetHostEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143996.aspx) to **try** to resolve the name, because **not every IP has a name**.

```
using System.Net;
...

public string GetHostName(string ipAddress)
{
    try
    {
        IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);
        if (entry != null)
        {
           return entry.HostName;
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
       //unknown host or
       //not every IP has a name
       //log exception (manage it)
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: SocketException solution ?

Answer (score 3):

If you've already got a list of ip adresses, you can find the name with:

```
      System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("youripaddress").HostName;
```

Comment: I get `SocketException`

Answer (score 2):

From the IP addresses, you could use the [`Dns.GetHostEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method.