# The network path was not found when using IP address instead of hostname of machine

Tags: c#, registry

Using below code, when I'm using IP Address (`"159.99.222.193"`) of machine, I'm getting error,

When passing host name of machine, it's working good. Whats need to be done to pass IP address?

> The network path was not found
>
> at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32ErrorStatic(Int32 errorCode, String str)
>      at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive hKey, String machineName, RegistryView view)
>      at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive hKey, String machineName)
>      at RegistryTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\h190733\source\repos\Registry\Registry\Program.cs:line 18

```
using (RegistryKey hive = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, "159.99.222.193"))
            {

                var key = hive.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\");

                string[] names = key.GetSubKeyNames();

                foreach (string entry in names)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(entry.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: I'm putting my some dummy ip addess

Comment: actual IP address for my machine is `159.99.222.193`

Comment: Any reason not to use the static variable `Registry.LocalMachine` for the same?

Comment: `Registry.LocalMachine` giving error for `OpenRemoteBaseKey`

Comment: See my answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55381535/5671993)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not pass the IP address to this method as it only accepts the host name.

Instead, try fetching the hostname by IP prior to calling the method.

```
IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);
var hostName = entry.HostName;
```

Then you can pass the hostname var into your `RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey` method.

You can also use the `Registry.LocalMachine` static variable to allow the library to fetch the hostname.

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit confuse about your question, the documentation for OpenRemoteBaseKey indicate machine name not IP.

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openremotebasekey?view=netframework-4.7.2

I presume in this contexte that machine name is hostname.

You can get hostname from ip before and use it in your call.

Like that :
[How to resolve hostname from local IP in C#.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123639/how-to-resolve-hostname-from-local-ip-in-c-net)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the static variable `Registry.LocalMachine` instead of opening `RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey`. See code below

```
using (var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\")) {
    string[] names = key.GetSubKeyNames();
    foreach (string entry in names) {
        Console.WriteLine(entry.ToString());
    }
}
```

The only reason to use `RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey`, is if the machine name is dynamically passed into the method - in that case, you wouldn't know you are accessing a local or a remote machine.